# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml when run the FlutterFire CLI command

Tags: flutter, firebase, command-line-interface

Getting  error when run the dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli in terminal.ru
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/ammar/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/quiver-3.2.1".

after login to the fierbase .I run the FlutterFire CLI command in terminal and it give the error

Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/ammar/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/quiver-3.2.1".

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that file it seems like. That is the file for all your dependencies. Did you delete it by any chance? By mistake perhaps?